# How do I get API error response in CatchError block in Angular 6?

Tags: angular, angular6

I am new in angular and Angular 6. I have an API and whose 400 bad request error like

```
POST /register 
{
    "success": false,
    "error": {
        "email": [
            "Enter a valid email address."
        ]
    }
}
```

I am trying to call API in angular like below

```
register(username: string, email: string, password, first_name: string, last_name: string) {
        return this.http.post<any>(this.registerURL,
            {"username": username, "password": password, "email": email, "first_name": first_name,
                "last_name": last_name})
            .pipe(map(user => {
                    if (user && user.token) {
                        localStorage.setItem('token', user.token);
                    }
                    return user;
                }),
                catchError((error: any) => {
                    return throwError(error);
                })
            );
    }
```

My question is how do I get API error response in CatchError block.

Answer (score 0):

you can access the complete response by providing the options object to HttpClient as described at [HttpClient](https://angular.io/guide/http#reading-the-full-response) Documentation.

```js
this.http.get<any>(
this.configUrl, { observe: 'response' });
```

Blitzstack example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lkxdwj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts

the response with headers and statusCode will be available as parameter to the catchError operator and the error callback of subscribe function.